# Clone VPS on Amazon AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hosting, vps, whm

My company has several websites hosted on a VPS, under Linux/CentOs/WHM/CPANEL

We are looking for a way to have desaster recovery fallback on another server, in case we face problems with our VPS.

On of the options we are cheking is to clone this VPS into Amazon AWS, and let it 'sleep' until the time we need it. This way we can pay only for storage.
Of course my intend to sunc the server on a regular basis (e.g. once a day/week), so to keep it up-to-date.

Having that in mind I would like to inqurie the following:
- Is is possible to clone a VPS server into AWS?
- Will it actually save us money - versus the option to buy another VPS that will be used as mirror (we currenly pay ~1000$ /year for the VPS)?
- Otherwise - what should be the best practive to approach such a website mirroring at an affordable cost?

Thanks
Yuval.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact a lot a companies use this kind of DR, and it is commonly called "Cold DR" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup_site#Cold_Sites)

You will only pay for the space reserved for your storage (S3, EBS, Glacier) and Route 53 Zones.

Just start the instances there, migrate the data you need, configure your instances properly and then stop them.

If you are using other DNS service I suggest you to migrate your DNS management to Route53, because then would be able to easily write a script to automatically change the DNS and then start your instances, or use Route 53 Health Check and DNS Failover (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover.html) plus a little bit o script to achieve a more automated solution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Felipe, Thanks for you reply. Do you happen to know if one can install an entire VPS backup into an AWS instance? I mean, can I prepare an image of my current VPS, and upload it to AWS seemlessly?

Comment: Oh yeah, sure you can. Generate an image and then import it for free. http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vmimport/